# Binding Variables In oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to oracle PL/SQL and wrote a piece of code for binding variables. I am not clear with the concept of how binding variables works and what is the purpose of USING clause.

I have written a piece of code to understand binding variables however its failing.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updNVAl(col IN VARCHAR2,val IN VARCHAR2)
 RETURN INTEGER
 IS
 BEGIN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'UPDATE emp SET '||col||' =:the_value' USING col,val;
    return SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  END;

  DECLARE
    val INTEGER;
  BEGIN
   val:= updNVAl('ename','deepak');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(val);
  END;
```

the error is :ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.UPDNVAL", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 4

help required.

Answer (score 3):

```
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
   'UPDATE emp SET '||col||' =:the_value' USING val;
```

You define only `:the_value` as bind variable, so just binding it is enough in your `USING` clause.

`col` actually, is formed as a String not a bind variable. Also note that the db objects(tables,columns..) cannot be used as bind elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updNVAl(ename IN VARCHAR2,val IN VARCHAR2)
  2   RETURN INTEGER
  3   IS
  4   BEGIN
  5      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  6      'UPDATE emp SET '||ename||' =:the_value' USING val;
  7      RETURN SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  8    END;
  9  /

Function created.

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
  2      val INTEGER;
  3    BEGIN
  4     val:= updNVAl('ename','deepak');
  5     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VAL);
  6    END;
  7  /
14

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select ename from emp;

ENAME
----------
deepak
deepak
deepak
deepak
deepak
deepak
deepak
deepak
deepak
deepak
deepak

ENAME
----------
deepak
deepak
deepak

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Bro, is it in any sense different from my answer?

Comment: I didn't notice your answer in front of my nose, my bad. sorry